# capistrano 3, rails 4, thin server strange exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, thin

I'm developing a Rails 4 app, I've setup my server to run thin and I'm trying to setup capistrano 3 for deployment. I'm developing on windows and deploying on linux.
Currently if fails on this line:

```
[f98408e4] Command: bundle exec thin restart -O -C config/thin/production.yml
```

With a very strange exception. The funny thing is that when I ssh to the server, navigate to the current release dir and execute that command manually it runs correctly. Maybe you'll see something I don't:

```
cap aborted!
bundle exec thin restart -O -C config/thin/production.yml stdout: Nothing written
bundle exec thin restart -O -C config/thin/production.yml stderr: Nothing written
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:125:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:149:in `block in _execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
config/deploy.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
config/deploy.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/sequential.rb:9:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/sequential.rb:8:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/sequential.rb:8:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/coordinator.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/dsl.rb:8:in `on'
config/deploy.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:14:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:14:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:64:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:63:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:63:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/bin/cap:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby200/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
```

My deploy.rb task about the restart looks like this:

```
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
set :rails_env, "production"
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      within release_path do
        execute "bundle exec thin restart -O -C config/thin/production.yml"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. But not always. Just from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      within release_path do
        execute :bundle, "exec thin restart -O -C config/thin/production.yml"
      end
    end
  end
  before :restart, 'rvm:hook'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> With a very strange exception. The funny thing is that when I ssh to the server, navigate to the current release dir and execute that command manually it runs correctly. Maybe you'll see something I don't:

http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

I'd try working through some of the suggestions to debug this listed there.